# Bootstrap add active class to nav bar when nav is a PHP include

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently building a site with bootstrap and would like to know if it's possible to, and how to add the class="active" attribute to a link on the nav menu. I saw another post similar to this on this very site, however it didn't work on the page using the Bootstrap carousel. I removed all links to jQuery and other javascript on the page but it still wasn't working.

On each page the nav is called with a php include, as is the code for the link state. So picture the markup like so:

```
<head>
<?php include_once('head.php'); ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php include_once('nav.php'); ?>
</body>
```

in the head.php is the following code, which I got from another post on this site:

```
<script>
/*menu handler*/
$(function(){
  function stripTrailingSlash(str) {
    if(str.substr(-1) == '/') {
      return str.substr(0, str.length - 1);
    }
    return str;
  }

  var url = window.location.pathname;  
  var activePage = stripTrailingSlash(url);

  $('.nav li a').each(function(){  
    var currentPage = stripTrailingSlash($(this).attr('href'));

    if (activePage == currentPage) {
      $(this).parent().addClass('active'); 
    } 
  });
});
</script>
```

and in the nav.php I've got:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" /></a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/template.php">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/index-template.php">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/index.php">Home</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

Each page is named as per the href attr.

This works on a duplicate of template.php, however it doesn't work on index.php, which is making me think it's something to do with the carousel...

I've also tried using the data-toggle="pill" as recommended somewhere but that doesn't work.

Any assistance will be appreciated. I'ts on a local vps at the moment, however I can assign it a public IP.

Thanks in advance!
Ash

Answer (score 2):

Because the script is being included in the head.php before the navbar has been loaded, it has nothing to apply the 'active' class to. Perhaps place the JavaScript in a separate include after the navbar.

If that doesn't work, I used this script to apply the active class to a specific menu item, just place it after the navbar include and change the href to the desired 'active' button

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="home.html"]').addClass('active');
});
</script>
```